# What's the differences of binding key?

Tags: key-bindings

```
(global-set-key [?\S- ] 'set-mark-command) 

(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c SPC") 'ace-jump-mode)
```

What's the differences and when to use what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [manual node on Commands for Key Bindings](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Commands.html), which I got from the first hit of a [google search for "emacs global-set-key"](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=emacs+global-set-key), says they're the same:

> Command: global-set-key key binding
>
> This function sets the binding of key in the current global map to binding.
>
> ```
>          (global-set-key key binding)
>          ==
>          (define-key (current-global-map) key binding)
> ```

If you look at the function definition for `global-set-key` (`C-h f global-set-key`, then follow the link to the source code), the function only does the following (ignoring the error checking code):

```
(define-key (current-global-map) key command)
```

And the docstring for `current-global-map` (again, `C-h f current-global-map`) says:

> Return the current global keymap.

Comment: The docs aren't always right, @Dan :)

Comment: @abo-abo: +1 for the interesting edge case in your answer.  My answer was meant more for pedagogical purposes: how one would go about answering this question on one's own.

Answer (score 4):

It's more or less the same.
The first thing expands to:

```
(progn (or (vectorp [?\S-]) (stringp [?\S-])
           (signal 'wrong-type-argument (list 'arrayp [?\S-])))
       (define-key (current-global-map) [?\S-] 'set-mark-command))
```

And since:

```
(eq (current-global-map) global-map)
; -> t
```

it's mostly equivalent to the second thing. I do prefer the
`global-set-key` though, since they're nicer semantic-wise.

### update: they aren't the same

```
(setq foobar (copy-keymap global-map))
(define-key foobar (kbd "C-.") 'forward-char)
(use-global-map foobar)
(eq (current-global-map) foobar)
;; -> t
(eq (current-global-map) global-map)
;; -> nil
```